# Unary fold with empty parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, fold

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t... items>
constexpr std::size_t count()
{
    return std::index_sequence<items...>().size();
}

template<std::size_t... items>
constexpr std::size_t fold_mul()
{
    if( count<items...>() == 0 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (... * items);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Result: " << fold_mul<>() << "\n";
}
```

This code is expected to output `1` but instead throws the error:

> <source>:19:28: error: fold of empty expansion over operator*
> 19 |         return (... * items);

**My question is:** Why doesn't this work, as the fold_expression is clearly in the `else` part.

For reference, this implementation works:

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr std::size_t fold_mul();

template<std::size_t... j>
requires (count<j...>() > 0)
constexpr std::size_t fold_mul()
{         
    return (j * ...);
}

template<>
constexpr std::size_t fold_mul()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you know that you can simply use `sizeof...(Args)` to obtain the length of `Args`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, when being specified fold expression with empty expansion, `(... * items)` is invalid at compile-time; even it won't be evaluated at run-time.

You can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17); then the else-part will be discarded when being specified fold expression with empty expansion.

> If the value is true, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise, *statement-true* is discarded.

```
template<std::size_t... items>
constexpr std::size_t count()
{
    return std::index_sequence<items...>().size();
}

template<std::size_t... items>
constexpr std::size_t fold_mul()
{
    if constexpr ( count<items...>() == 0 )
    // ^^^^^^^^^
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (... * items);
    }
}
```

Comment: or simply `return (1 * ... * items);` :-)

Answer (score 8):

The only fold-expressions that have a default value for an empty sequence are `&&` (defaults to `true`), `||` (defaults to `false`), and `,` (defaults to `void()`).

`*` doesn't have a default as far as the language is concerned. But in this case, we can use a binary fold instead of a unary fold:

```cpp
template<std::size_t... items>
constexpr std::size_t fold_mul()
{
    return (1 * ... * items);
}
```

This works in the empty case (the value is just `1`) and in the non-empty case (since `1` is the identity element for multiplication, so doesn't change the value).